# Визуальные интерфейсы

Tags: windows, gui

На чем пишут "богатые" визуальные интерфейсы для Win32 Desktop? Я имею в виду со всякими там "финтифлюшечками" вроде градиентов на кнопках, скругленных краёв, и прочих эффектов. Какие наиболее широко используемые фреймворки, или возможно надстройки над DirectX?
Очень бы хотелось знать, за последние пять лет вообще очень отстал в программировании, столько всего изменилось. Похоже стандартный набор GUI из comctl32.lib вообще уже мало кто использует. Как вообще делают кастомные элементы GUI, наподобии того, что в 3ds max или скажем Yahoo Messenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надстройка на DirectX есть. [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) называется.
Можете посмотреть в интернете примеры интерфейсов на WPF.

Вот примеры коммерческих контролов для WPF:

- [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/#main|gallery)
- [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx)
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/controls.aspx)

Бесплатные

- [Odyssey](http://odyssey.codeplex.com/)
- [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/sdks/entry343871.aspx)

В настоящее время WPF является наиболее прогрессивной технологией разработки интерфейсов под все платформы Windows - настольные, мобильные, интернет-приложения (Silverlight). Даже .NET Micro Framework для микроконтроллеров содержит в себе урезанную реализацию WPF.

Ну а профессионалы по WinForms дополнят мой ответ со своей стороны.

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows и с использованием Windows-средств нужно? Я пишу кроссплатформенные приложения с использованием Qt + QML. "Финтифлюшечки" присуствуют. Плюс можно скомпилировать хоть под Win, хоть под Lin, хоть под Mac.